# JS function to coffeescript, with jQuery .map and Selectors as param

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm refactoring some JS code to CoffeeScript, and having a problem with a function.

This is the JS that works:

```
$(".comformt_QA").change(function(){
   var array = $(".comformt_QA").map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
   }).toArray();

   $("[name='comfort_qualitative_assessment.global_comfort_index']").val(
      calc_qualitative_assessment_array(array)
   ).change();
});
```

My goal is to use this snipplet as a function, and be able to call:

```
class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array(".comformt_QA", "[name='comfort_qualitative_assessment.global_comfort_index']");
```

Here's the CoffeeScript:

```
@class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array = (class_param, target) ->
   array = []
   $(class_param).change ->
      array = $(class_param).map( ->
         $(this).val()
      )
   $(target).val(calc_qualitative_assessment_array(array)).change()
```

array is always empty...
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your coffee code to Javascript this would be the result:

```
this.class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array = function(class_param, target) {
  var array;
  array = [];
  $(class_param).change(function() {
    return array = $(class_param).map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    });
  });
  return $(target).val(calc_qualitative_assessment_array(array)).change();
};
```

Coffeescript transpiles the `@` to the `this` keyword in JS. Also you don't have returns within your function - this leads to coffeescript returning the last assigned value of the function.

Maybe this would be a working approach:

```
class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array = (class_param, target) ->
   array = []
   $(class_param).change ->
      array = $(class_param).map( ->
         $(@).val()
      )
      return
   $(target).val(calc_qualitative_assessment_array(array)).change()
   return
```

Transpiled this looks like this:

```
var class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array;

class_to_calc_qualitative_assessment_array = function(class_param, target) {
  var array;
  array = [];
  $(class_param).change(function() {
    array = $(class_param).map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    });
  });
  $(target).val(calc_qualitative_assessment_array(array)).change();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code still doesn't work though :/ I'm having doubts that the `$(class_param).change` and `$(class_param).map` are functioning correctly